# Receiving from message queues

Tags: c, operating-system, ipc

I have successfully created the message queue by using the following command:

```
msgIdHareTurtle =  msgget(keyHareTurtle, 0644 | IPC_CREAT | O_NONBLOCK);
```

Now I want to send the queue to some other process I used,

```
msgsnd(msgIdHareTurtle, (struct msgbuf *)&bufHareTurtle, sizeof(int), IPC_NOWAIT);
```

and I try to receive it in different process by:

```
msgrcv(msgIdHareTurtle, (struct msgbuf *)&bufHareTurtle, sizeof(int), 0, IPC_NOWAIT);
```

my structure bufHareTurtle is of following type:

```
typedef struct smsgbuf{
    long mtype;
    unsigned int position;
} smsgbuf;
```

My question: The sending was successful and the program(both the processes) is running too but whenever I am sending an unsigned integer for example 2 , I AM ALWAYS GETTING THE RECEIVED VALUE (IN LATTER PROCESS) AS 0 EVRYTIME. Could somebody tell me what is the error in this code or what could be possible error elsewhere.

Comment: this 2 is the value of the position variable

Comment: Check the return value of msgrcv and msgsnd and be sure that mtype > 0.

Comment: You're doing non-blocking reads/writes (IPC_NOWAIT), are you sure you really got a message ?

Comment: We've seen a lot of hare-and-turtle questions the past few weeks.  Everybody going to the same school?

Comment: I got it .. this was probably due to the mtype = 0 as Daniel mentioned
@Hans : yes its from our department of CS, IIT Delhi. We are really struck on it. Can you help me (give me a code) to write an INTEGER to the shared memory?

Comment: I think the dept of CS at IIT Delhi should support their students instead of the volunteers at stackoverflow.com.  I have yet to see a significant contribution made by anybody from that school.  These kind of practices destroy the value of a web site like this when the volunteers give up, disgusted with having to look at the same crummy question over and over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was there in synchronization. The sending to the queue was delayed due to sleep inserted in between. I corrected it and the error was gone